# Set CONTAINS as the default in Google Data Studio Search Filter

Tags: looker-studio

I have a search query box in which the user inputs her keyword to search. However the user must switch from EQUALS to CONTAINS to maximize her search.

How do I set the query type to CONTAINS as a default (currently EQUALS is set as the default).

Thank you.

Link to the problem:  https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/43874948-585e-43f9-ba65-161afe3e7a32/page/YHe1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update (Apr 2021): This is now possible. See @Nimantha's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447403/4024072) for the correct answer.

Original (Dec 2019): This is not possible right now (Dec 2019). However, you can put in a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=196095&template=1100266

Answer (score 3):

### 1) Contains (Update: 20 Aug 2020)

It can now be achieved by:

**1.1) Control**

- Add a Control > Input Box

**1.2) Data Tab**

- Select the required Dimension

**1.3) Style Tab**

- ***Search Type***: Contains
- ***Label Position***: Hidden

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b0e69dbc-c960-4f54-96b8-9c3c78b86531/page/oNhcB) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

### 2) Original Post

One way it could be achieved is by using the recently released [Search Box Community Visualization](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9e9729dc-203f-4679-8e14-2958e28f405a/page/N7lSB).

After a bit of side-by-side testing, 3 key points stood out compared to the Search All [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) currently implemented in the respective report provided in the question:

- Filter by Contains
- Filter while Typing
- CaSe InSeNsItIvE

Feel free to have a look through and test out the [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b0e69dbc-c960-4f54-96b8-9c3c78b86531) used to explain the below:

**1) Community Visualisation Access**

- At the Data Source, ensure that Community Visualisation Access is turned On.
- GIF ([From Earlier Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61883130/12892553)) to elaborate on #1:
  [image]

**2) Search Box (Location)**

- Add the component to the Report by clicking on the `Community Visualisations and Components` button and selecting the component and placing it on the Report.
- GIF to demonstrate #2:
  [image]

**3) CSV Filter Control (Usage)**

- ***Column to Search on***: Add the required Field
- ***Interactions***: (Tick) Apply filter
- GIF to visualise #3:
  [image]