# How to Filter CSV (Comma-separated values) in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm currently building a dashboard and I was hoping to have a way that users could filter without having to edit the dashboard at all.  I have a Data set similar to this:

```
Object      Tags
Example 1   dog, cat, pets
Example 2   pets, bird
Example 3   bird, home decor
```

I want to have a table in Google Data Studio that shows these details then additionally a filter where you can type in any text and it will filter by only records where your text is contained in "Tags".

For example, I could type in "bird" and then only the records for "Example 2" and "Example 3" would show in the table.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it could be achieved is by using the recently released [CSV Filter Control Community Visualization](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/2b0a22a2-3992-49e1-be12-bdc22937daea/page/QPvLB):

**1) Community Visualisation Access**

- At the Data Source, ensure that Community Visualisation Access is turned On.
- GIF to elaborate on #1:
  [image]

**2) CSV Filter Control (Location)**

- Add the component to the Report by clicking on the `Community Visualisations and Components` button and selecting the component and placing it on the Report.
- GIF to demonstrate #2:
  [image]

**3) CSV Filter Control (Usage)**

- ***Column to Filter on***: Tags
- ***Interactions***: (Tick) Apply filter
- ***View Mode***: Single-select or Multi-select the required values
- [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c298eebd-3d07-494e-9632-0aa1d2746706) and GIF to visualise #3:
  [image]